# Bitwise representation of Huffman header information converted to its character representation

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, huffman-code

I am trying to take a bitstream(gibberish/garbage) that is the Huffman header topology (eventually I will use it to build the Huffman tree) and convert it to is correct characters, 1s, and 0s.
Attached is my example, the header info for go go gophers, I have the binary representation written out and where the 1, 0, and letters are found within it. I just am not sure how to create a C function to convert the bitstream to the character representation.
To further explain I have a bitstream of random characters ect that represent "1g1o01s1 01e1h01p1r00000", but I don't know how to covert it. It should be mentioned that the characters are represented by their ASCII binary value, but the 1 and 0s are not, they are just bits.

[image: huffman bit - header]

Comment: So by "ASCII" are you saying that `'g`' is **seven** bits `1100111`? The exclamations `!` in your diagram suggest it is **eight** bits encoded.

Comment: The diagram looks like there is always a `1` bit followed by eight character bits, each as a `0` bit plus seven more, and you have been careless in marking them off, because one group has only six bits.

Comment: My apologies on the diagram, I was just trying to sketch stuff out to better understand. I believe you are right in saying every character has 7 bits with a leading zero bit. And yes when I say ASCII I mean that seven is represented by seven bits 1100111, with a leading zero bit in this case